# Can't SSH to local area from DHCP server 2 NICs

Tags: networking

Rephrased entire question. I messed up and had to reinstall OS of DHCP server and now can't get the DHCP server to ssh into anything on its local network.

The server has 2 network interfaces. **eno1** (to internet/router) and **eno2** (local, server to server).

My Host is **192.168.1.1** my other servers are **192.168.1.20 & 21**

I did a ping test and this is what I got.

```
[darius@HostServer ~]$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.051/0.089/0.027 ms
[darius@HostServer ~]$ ping 192.168.1.20
PING 192.168.1.20 (192.168.1.20) 56(84) bytes of data.
################## WHY THIS IP?! ###########
From 66.75.161.49 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
######################################
^C
--- 192.168.1.20 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

[darius@HostServer ~]$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.035 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.028 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 2999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.028/0.041/0.075/0.020 ms
```

I've restarted network and dhcp numerous times. I don't get it.. I can't connect from .20 or .21 to .1 nor vice-versa.

Comment: Just a small update. Tried pinging again and finally got a response, got "Time to live exceeded".

Comment: Realized it's pinging wrong IP.. it switches from 192 to a 66.xx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from the error that you need to edit the default interface for the dhcp service to listen on.

Try adding INTERFACES="eno2" to your /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server file (assuming this is isc-dhcp-server).

As far as being able to SSH/ping to the dhcp, it sounds like the dhcp server is not in the dns or it's a different IP now (since you re-installed).

Comment: I found the issue. I noticed the NIC was using /32 instead of /24 after ip address. Don't know how that changed.